# Nothing is static and I get an error about a non-static field

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I really have no idea how to word this question so I'll just explain the situation.

I have a form with a binding source "classBindingSource" and from another form I want to add objects to this binding source so from in that form I wrote the method

```
public void addClass(Class new_class)
    {
        classBindingSource.Add(new_class);
    }
```

however when I call that method from my second form with this method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = textBox1.Text;
            Class new_class = new Class(name);
            Form1.addClass(new_class);
        }
```

I get the following error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property GPACalculator.Form1.addClass(GPACalculator.Class)'

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling this method via it's class name instead of an instance of the class. That's why it's required that the method is static.

```
Form1.addClass(new_class);
```

So either make it static(what does not work since you need to access controls of the form like the `BindingSource`) or use an instance of `Form1`. You could pass the `Form1` instance to `Form2` when you create and open it, for example via constructor or property.

(presuming that you have a non-static(!) property `Opener` of type `Form1`)

```
Opener.addClass(new_class);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error is telling you, you need an instance of that form. Something like this:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
string name = textBox1.Text;
Class new_class = new Class(name);
myForm.addClass(new_class);
```

You are probably opening the Form like this: `Form1.Show();`, which is wrong. You need an instance as shown above, and then call the `.Show()` of the declared instance.